# Simple list in a python program doesn't yield results

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve an exercise that asks me the following:

Create a string that is a long series of words separated by spaces

Turn the string into a list of words using split

Delete three words from the list, but delete each one using a different kind of Python operation

Sort the list

Add new words to the list using three different kinds of Python operation

Turn the list of words back into a single string using join

Print the string

That's what I did:

```
def clubs(t):
    england = 'Tottenham Burnley Newcastle Leicester Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal'
    t = england.split() 
    t = england.pop(1)
    del england[3]
    england.remove('Newcastle')
    england.sort()
    england.append('Juventus')
    spain = 'Sevilla, Barcelona'
    england.extend(spain)
    england.insert('Lazio')
    delimiter = ' '
    t = delimiter.join(england)
    print(england)
```

The output that I expected was:

> Tottenham Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal Juventus Sevilla
>   Barcelona Lazio

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with it?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue with this code or the error message with this code?

Comment: I'm confused as `t` is an input variable into your function but you are mutating its contents inside the method.

Comment: in second line you have to reassign `england = england.split()`, then spain is to be splitted as well assuming you want 2 items to be appended to the endland list and insert take 2 args first is index and second is the obj to be inserted, I have posted the updated code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the england string and the list you are generating from this string with split.
Also your output should be sorted so It would be 
Arsenal Cardiff Chelsea Everton Leicester Tottenham Juventus Sevilla Barcelona Lazio

so I would do it like below

```
def clubs(t):
     england = 'Tottenham Burnley Newcastle Leicester Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal'
     t = england.split() 
     t.pop(1)
     del t[3]
     t.remove('Newcastle')
     t.sort()
     t.append('Juventus')
     spain = 'Sevilla Barcelona'
     t.extend(spain.split())
     t.insert(len(t),'Lazio')
     delimiter = ' '
     new_string = delimiter.join(t)
     print(new_string)
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
def clubs():
    england = 'Tottenham Burnley Newcastle Leicester Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal'
    england = england.split()
    t = england.pop(1)
    del england[2]
    england.remove('Newcastle')
    # england.sort()
    england.append('Juventus')
    spain = 'Sevilla, Barcelona'
    england.extend(spain.split(','))
    england.insert(len(england), 'Lazio')
    delimiter = ' '
    t = delimiter.join(england)
    print(england)
    print(t)


clubs()
```

Output:

```
['Tottenham', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea', 'Cardiff', 'Everton', 'Arsenal', 'Juventus', 'Sevilla', ' Barcelona', 'Lazio']
Tottenham Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal Juventus Sevilla  Barcelona Lazio
```

Explanation:

- There was no need to pass an argument to the function.
- It should be `del england[2]` not `del england[3]`
- `sort()` will sort in alphabetical order.
- It should be `england.extend(spain.split(','))` other wise it will extend using each alphabet.
- It should be `england.insert(len(england), 'Lazio')`, so that `Lazio` will be inserted at the last.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! Neat explanation, I was able to understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The updated code:

```
def clubs(t):
        england = 'Tottenham Burnley Newcastle Leicester Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal'
        england = england.split()
        england.pop(1)
        del england[3]
        england.remove('Newcastle')
        england.sort()
        england.append('Juventus')
        spain = 'Sevilla, Barcelona'
        spain = spain.split(",")
        england.extend(spain)
        england.insert(0, 'Lazio')
        delimiter = ' '
        england = delimiter.join(england)
        # t = delimiter.join(england)
        print(england)
    clubs("")
```

Following things which you missed are:

1. `insert` takes 2 args first is index and second object to be inserted.
2. you have to reassign england when you are doing split as you .split() returns the list which has to be reassigned to england for below functions to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm now able to understand it better and my program yield expected result, cheers!

Comment: glad, it helped

Answer (score 0):

england is a a string variable. Since you slpit the string into list at t, t is what you want to work with

```py
def clubs():
    england = 'Tottenham Burnley Newcastle Leicester Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal'
    t = england.split() 
    t.pop(1)
    del t[3]
    t.remove('Newcastle')
    t.sort()
    t.append('Juventus')
    spain = 'Sevilla Barcelona'
    t.extend(spain.split())
    t.insert(len(t),'Lazio')
    delimiter = ' '
    new_string = delimiter.join(t)
    print(new_string)

clubs()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clubs(t):
    england = 'Tottenham Burnley Newcastle Leicester Liverpool Chelsea Cardiff Everton Arsenal'
    england = england.split()#now england is list earlier it was string and t was list
    t=england.pop(1)
    del england[3]
    england.remove('Newcastle')
    england.sort()
    england.append('Juventus')
    spain = ['Sevilla', 'Barcelona'] 
    england.extend(spain)#if extend is used with string then it adds each element of string as an element to list so spain should had been a list
    england.insert(2,'Lazio')#insert function takes exactly 2 arguments (pos,element) only element was given earlier
    delimiter = ' '
    t = delimiter.join(england)
    print(england)
```

Output

````
['Arsenal', 'Cardiff', 'Lazio', 'Chelsea', 'Everton', 'Leicester', 'Tottenham', 'Juventus', 'Sevilla', 'Barcelona']```
````